# How would you solve this logarithmic equation with both $\log n$ and $n$ terms?

Tags: logarithms

I have a small logarithm related question that I do not seem to understand how to solve.

If a program takes $\log n$ microseconds to run a program of size $n$, what is the maximum size of a program that can run in $1$ second? Here, the base of the logarithm is $2$.

I end up with an equation - $(n 10^6)/ \log n =$ maximum size of the program that can run in $1$ second. However, I'm unsure on how to solve this further.

The answer I found for this question is $2^{(10^6)}$. However, the steps to obtain this answer were not shown. May I please know how to solve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your equation.  You should have

$$\log n=10^6$$

or the time it takes to run a program of size $n$ is one million microseconds.  Now just solve for $n$.

Comment: I figured that. But I'm unsure of how to obtain that equation you mentioned from the problem statement. Could you please edit your answer to include that?

Comment: @user3705895 I think I more or less said it in English.  "The time it takes to run a program of size $n$", which according to your problem is $\log n$, "is (equals) one million microseconds."

Comment: Got it. Thanks.